# Ignoring duplicates within elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have many records where the msg is 'a'. Some of these records have the same type.

I'm trying to write a query that counts the number of with msg 'a', but doesn't count duplicates.

Example:

- 1: msg = 'a', type = 'b'
- 2: msg = 'a', type = 'b'
- 3: msg = 'a', type
  = 'c'

This should return a count of two because the first and second records have the same type and are only counted once.

Here is my query so far.

```
body: {
  query: {
    bool: {
      must: [
        {
          range: {
            "@timestamp" => { from: 'now-1d', to: 'now' }
          }
        },
        { match: { msg: 'a' }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You explained what results you're expecting . Can you explain what results you got?

Comment: The current query I'm using counts records twice even if they have the same 'type' attribute. I'd like it to only count records with the same type once.

Comment: The query you posted doesn't count anything. What do you mean by "counting"? Do you count inside of your client app?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify. I'm passing that to the count method in the Elasticsearch Ruby API wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Try using aggregations they'll count it for you :)
Read here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html

And try something like this:

```
body:{
query: {
    bool: {
      must: [
        {
          range: {
            "@timestamp" => { from: 'now-1d', to: 'now' }
          }
        },
        { match: { msg: 'a' }}
      ]
    }
  }
},
  aggs:{
     "type":{
        "terms":{
              "field":"type"
         }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: I was able to get it to work by using the cardinality aggregation. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sure thing :) You can up vote or accept the answer , FYI :)